# PHP Multi-format file search

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, scripting

So, I've been scratching my head at this for a while, seeing as how I've got no experience working with PHP and file...anything.  The functionality I'm looking for is to parse a JSON array into PHP from a mixed format file (in this specific case, a WoT replay file), so that I can output some information.  pastebin due to size:
http://pastebin.com/4vtqyBNr

That's missing most of the file (the rest being data from the program itself), however there are { } and [ ] mixed into the rest of the files data as well.

Question being:  How do I pull the Json array, and only the Json array out of the file?

Comment: From what I can see from the file, you should just get rid of the header part of the file. Parse the file string and delete everything before the first '{'. Using trim() could be useful as well.

Comment: hmm, that actually would work pretty well. -facepalms-

Do that, limit the return to two arrays, and bam.  everything works out.

Thanks ^^,